# activerecord make pk refernce to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I Have a Table Schema like:

Table `users`:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
      t.int :pk, :limit => 8, primary: true,null: false
      t.string :username
      t.int :follower_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index "users", ["pk"], name: "index_users_on_pk", unique: true, using: :btree

  end
end
```

and Table `stats`:

```
class CreateStats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :stats,id: false do |t|
      t.int :pk, :limit => 8, primary: true,null: false
      t.int :state

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index "stats", ["pk"], name: "index_stats_on_pk", unique: true, using: :btree
    add_reference :stats, :users, index: true
  end
end
```

column `pk` is the bigint column for table `users` and table `stats`. 
the line `add_reference :stats, :users, index: true` adds new column `user_id` to table.
I want to make a one to one reference like `stats.pk belongs to users.pk`.

How to do that?

Comment: both one-to-one and one-to-many relationships have a foreign key (in your case `user_id`) in one of the tables (`stats`). the only difference comes in your model definition, whether you define a `has_one` relationship in `User` model, or `has_many`. In the `Stat` model it will always be `belongs_to`

Comment: i dont want to create a new column `user_id`. i want make link on the `pk`. like http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/

Comment: ok so you want to make the `stat`'s primary key to act as the foreign key as well ? in that case, remove the `add_reference` line from your migration. in your `stat` model indicate that the foreign key is your `pk` column:  `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "pk"`. See it it works